# Why does onChange only work once per value

Tags: javascript, html

Each time the web page is loaded the onchange method works, but it only works once per value. When summer is selected the classes are added, when i chose winter the class is added but then if i chosesummer again it will not work. Why is this?

```js
 const landingBGR = document.querySelector(".landing-wrapper");
    const landingBTN = document.getElementById("l-btn");

    function selectedSeason(season) {
    
    switch(season) {
        case "summer":
            landingBTN.setAttribute("href","summer.html"); 
            landingBGR.classList.add("summer-bgr");
            break;

        case "winter":
            landingBTN.setAttribute("href","winter.html");
            landingBGR.classList.add("winter-bgr");
            break;
         }
    }
```

```html
<select name="" id="landing-drop" onchange="oninput(this.value)">
            <option value="">Ireland in the four Seasons</option>
            <option value="summer">Summer</option>
            <option value="winter">Winter</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, code updated to make it more clear

Comment: `onchange` works each time for me when select input value is changed

Comment: yes but when you redo a value does it still work?

Comment: Try selecting summer, then winter, then summer.

Comment: @user10431501 yep

Comment: Weird, I wonder why it is not working for me?

Comment: @user10431501 Try to use `oninput` instead of `onchange`, same behavior?

Comment: Yup, same behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to delete the old class when you select a new option.

```
landingBGR.classList.remove("summer-bgr");

landingBGR.classList.remove("winter-bgr");
```

you will maybe need

```
if(landingBGR.classList.contains("classname"))
```